# Ember JS: Access peekAll length in console

Tags: ember.js

I am using the following code in my router in the Model hook.

```
const listings = this.store.peekAll('listings');
console.log(listings); // returns a class with a length of 6
console.log(listings.length); // return 0
```

I am trying to find a way to access the length in the console. I have read its not available in the console but I'm sure there must be a way.

Answer (score 2):

The `peekAll` method returns an `ArrayProxy` [from ember-data](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/ArrayProxy). You can get access to the contents of that array (and call length/map/etc) on it with `.toArray()`. So this should work:

```js
const listings = this.store.peekAll('listings');
console.log(listings.toArray().length);
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it did not work in my case. I was able to access the store.length on the next page however with a regular .length. I suspect even though I could see the data in the contents it wasnt actually loaded yet?

Comment: Can you add some details about what "did not work" means? Did you get an error? Or just a count of 0?

Comment: Hi, just a count of 0

Comment: That's actually to be expected if the data isn't loaded. When you use `peekRecord` or `peekAll` the data won't be fetched from the server. I would guess that on the next page you have a call to `find` or `findAll` that is filling the store with your data and then `peek` will show that data.

Answer (score 0):

use **get** property

const listings = this.store.peekAll('listings');
let listings_length = get(listings, 'length');